# Flutter testing, Could not find an option named "driver"

Tags: flutter

i'm getting this error even though my test_driver file is outside lib, can you help?

> Target file " --driver=test_driver/test_driver.dart" not found.

I tried to do flutter testing, but the flutter file can't find my way.